# Getting Month End Dates for a date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

I have a table which will give me name and start date.Using this i need to get records with name and month end date rows from the start date till date.
My basic table has something like below

```
Name    | Start_date
Fly     | 01-Jul-16
```

My output would be like below

```
Name    Start_date
Fly| 31-Jul-16
Fly 31-Aug-16
Fly 30-Sep-16
Fly 31-Oct-16
Fly 30-Nov-16
Fly 31-Dec-16
Fly 31-Jan-17
Fly 28-Feb-17
Fly 31-Mar-17
Fly 30-Apr-17
Fly 31-May-17
Fly 30-Jun-17
Fly 31-Jul-17
Fly 31-Aug-17
```

I have tried few things using connect by level and used last day function,but that table is not having name to join to the basic table.I have more than 100 names in my table .Request you to guide on this.

Comment: You could also post your trials here, which will help to identify the problem

Comment: Do you only have one name and one date, or several rows at the same time? And if more than one row (more than one name and one date), are the names distinct?

Comment: I have only one name and one date

Comment: You just edited the post to say "I have **more than 100 names**" and in reply to me you say "I have only one name"? What the heck?

Comment: Sry i meant the name column is distinct in my table.Apologies for misguiding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it if you have more than one name and one date, but it works only if the input names are distinct. (Otherwise the query can be modified to accommodate non-unique names.)

Strange that you want the month-end dates to be called `start_date`, the same as in the input data. Also, `name` is an Oracle keyword which should not be used as a column name. I will let you take care of both issues.

```
with
     test_data ( name, start_date ) as (
       select 'Fly', to_date('01-Jul-16', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
       select 'Two', to_date('15-Feb-17', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- Use your actual table and column names in the SQL below.
select     name, add_months(last_day(start_date), level - 1) as start_date
from       test_data
connect by add_months(last_day(start_date), level - 1) <= last_day(sysdate)
       and prior name = name
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by   name, start_date
;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME  START_DATE
---   ----------
Fly   31-Jul-16 
Fly   31-Aug-16 
Fly   30-Sep-16 
Fly   31-Oct-16 
Fly   30-Nov-16 
Fly   31-Dec-16 
Fly   31-Jan-17 
Fly   28-Feb-17 
Fly   31-Mar-17 
Fly   30-Apr-17 
Fly   31-May-17 
Fly   30-Jun-17 
Fly   31-Jul-17 
Fly   31-Aug-17 
Two   28-Feb-17 
Two   31-Mar-17 
Two   30-Apr-17 
Two   31-May-17 
Two   30-Jun-17 
Two   31-Jul-17 
Two   31-Aug-17
```

Comment: Thanks mathguy.That really helped .Will frame my questions better next time around.The query has sys_guid ,will this be an issue if the query is being used by a dot net application